# Why cant I use ri from terminal

Tags: ruby

```
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro-2:pickaxe jod$ ri ActiveRecord::Base#save
Nothing known about ActiveRecord
```

This should be working but maybe its not installed? I thought it came with ruby. Ruby, Rails and IRB are working fine.

Comment: It doesn't come with ruby.

Comment: when you installed the rails gem, did it say it created the ri?

Comment: You are using it from the terminal, without error.  It is simply that nothing is known about ActiveRecord.  If you installed the gem with the setting --no-ri (sometimes people also add --no-rdoc) then it wno't generate the documentation for you.  This is normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the rdoc data. Here's how:

```
gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install; gem rdoc --all --overwrite
```

or if you're using RVM:

```
rvm docs generate-ri
```

Then you should be able to make your `ri` query as posted and get the expected output.